# Getting only numbers after and before alphabets

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have few telephone number like this:

```
            Tele
            -----
            251510X25    
            364680X5 
            12345,X34
            12345X
            x57823889
            1234567X12/7
            1234567X,12/7
```

I want rto get the telephone  having numeric before and after X only
My output should be:

```
            Tele
            -----
            251510X25    
            364680X5 
            1234567X12/7
```

I have written a query like this:

```
            SELECT ID,TELP,
                 CASE 
                     WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', TELP) >0  THEN 
                         RTRIM(LEFT(TELP, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', TELP)-1)) 
                     ELSE TELP 
                 END as TELP1
             FROM [teble1] where len(TELP) <=10 and PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', TELP) >0 
             and (TELP like '%x%' or TELP like '%/%')
```

I 'm unable to get the desired output. I have around 100k records like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LIKE` operator can work here:

```
SELECT *
FROM [teble1]
WHERE
    TELP LIKE '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]X[0-9]%';
```

The above like pattern says to capture any number having seven digits, followed by an `X`, followed by at least one digit afterwards.

SQL Server does not have very strong regex support, but to compensate for that, they enhanced `LIKE` to support some basic regex pattern matching, such as `[0-9]` to represent any digit.

Comment: I have to get numbers having the slash (\) also.

Comment: @AskMe My query would return the third record of your expected output, and your first two records _don't_ have slash.  Can you explain your problem better?

Comment: OK. Thanks. Will check again. Also, I'm interested to get 7 digit numbers before X

Comment: @AskMe I updated my query again with a different pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I think simple `PATINDEX()` function would work here to get the rto telephone numbers

```
SELECT * 
FROM table t
WHERE PATINDEX('%[0-9]X[^,]%', tele) > 0
```

In order to get only telephone number which has the numer berfore and after x then format might slight change

```
PATINDEX('%[0-9]X[0-9]%', tele) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   ;WITH CTE AS
    (
        SELECT REPLACE(Tele,'/','') V, Tele , CHARINDEX('X',Tele,0) Ix
        FROM tableName 
    )
    SELECT Tele
    FROM CTE
    WHERE 
    TRY_CAST(SUBSTRING(V,0,Ix) AS BIGINT) IS NOT NULL AND SUBSTRING(V,0,Ix) <> '' 
    AND TRY_CAST(SUBSTRING(V,Ix+1,100) AS BIGINT) IS NOT NULL AND SUBSTRING(V,Ix+1,100) <> ''
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give the result you asked for: -

```
SELECT *
FROM teble1
WHERE
TELP LIKE '%[0-9]X[0-9]%';
```

Comment: From what I understand, the OP wants to assert that there are _seven_ digits before the `X`, not just one.

Comment: I get that, but i was trying to give the result asked for: -

as said in Question, My output should be:
            Tele
            -----
            251510X25    
            364680X5 
            1234567X12/7